# How to call servlet from JSP which is in a subpackage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to call servlet from JSP which is present inside a subpackage?
The servlet is present inside Source Packages" folder. Name of servlet is:

```
servlets.io.registration.servlet1.java
```

Now i want to call this servlet from JSP page,

```
<form name="admin-form" action="/*Path of servlet goes here*/">
```

But this is not working.

Comment: You don't call a servlet by it's class name or package, you call it by URL pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, for Servlets you can give them an address relative to your context root.

With any J2EE container with the Servlet 3.0 API (for instance Glassfish 4) you can annotate servlets with `@WebServlet("path")`, setting their path, for instance `@WebServlet("/someservlet")`. You can even use subpaths, like `@WebService("path/sub/someservlet")`.

So assuming your J2EE application is called "Registration", running on port 8080 and you put this on top of your Servlet class: `@WebServlet("/someservlet")`, you can set the action to `http://yourserver.com:8080/Registration/someservlet`

Comment: how to do it without annotations?

Comment: inside class or outside the class?

Comment: Do you have a class which extends HttpServlet? If so, you should put it in there.

Comment: I used `@WebServlet` but i am getting this error: `cannot find symbol. symbol: class WebServlet location: myservlet`

Comment: You need to import the package it's in, put this on top: `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;`

Answer (score 0):

Use WebRequest annotation on your servlet to configure whatever path you like:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/myservletpath")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html